# Zero inflated generalized poisson: How can I compare 2 models?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, goodness-of-fit, poisson-regression, zero-inflation

I'm using Statsmodels to fit count data by Zero Inflated Poisson Regression.
Suppose that I have 2 models:

```
m1 = ZeroInflatedPoisson(y_train, x_train_1, x_train_infl_1, inflation='logit')
m2 = ZeroInflatedPoisson(y_train, x_train_2, x_train_infl_2, inflation='logit')
```

What is the method and statistical metric to know if model 2 significantly fits data better than model 1?

By the way, I worked with GLM Poisson Regression before and there is Chi-squared test to test if 2 **nested models** are significantly better using Deviance statistic. However, in Zero Inflated Poisson Regression, there is no Deviance statistic? Do you know why?

And is there any definition for **nested models** in Zero Inflated Poisson Regression?

Thank you very much!

Comment: loglikelihood based statistics, llf, aic, bic, are available in the models, but statsmodels doesn't have LR-test for those models yet.